# Bug: Missing ionicons.woff in www/build/fonts/

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular, ionic2

I got the following error in the browser when I ran ionic serve from a freshly made tabs starter app.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8100/build/fonts/ionicons.woff?v=3.0.0-alpha.3
ionicons.woff is referenced in www/build/css/app.ios.css.
```

Here's my ionic info:

```
$ ionic info
Your system information:
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
OS
Node Version: v6.7.0
```

error photo

[image]